# Can we use an existing Win32 dll in UWP app without having source code for the dll

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, uwp, dllexport

[project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6pgd.png)I have an existing C++ unmanaged Win32 dll project (i have the source code for it), but this project uses a third party win32 dll for logging (log4cplus) whose source code i don't have. Is it possible to create a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app that can use these dlls.

Comment: Isn't log4cplus an open-source project?

Comment: UWP is native code. You can use a native, unmanaged DLL from native code, so long as it doesn't use any API's unavailable in the UWP.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done for app packages using the Desktop Bridge (http://aka.ms/desktopbridge), but for pure UWP packages you need to link the library with the /APPCONTAINER flag in order to pass the WACK (Windows App Certification Kit) test for Store onboarding.

Once linked with that flag you will get past that certification test and then the WACK will also verify that the library only calls UWP-compliant APIs. This may or may not require additional changes in order to make the library compliant for Store submission.

Comment: Won't win32 DLLs automatically fail wack due to missing /APPCONTAINER linker flag?

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I was thinking "desktop bridge package" when writing my answer. Updating it now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I followed this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx "Using a Win32 DLL in a Universal Windows Platform App" to create a test Win32 dll project. Then i added reference to Log4cplus by including header files, lib and dll, but it still gives me linker error. I figured out that while compiling the project with the properties mentioned in the above link, the Project defaults under Configuration properties doesn't have any option to change character set to multibyte, that is what causing this issue. Is there any way to resolve this.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT can you provide any walk-through/sample code or blog (any kind of reference regarding **linking the library with the /APPCONTAINER flag in order to pass the WACK (Windows App Certification Kit) test for Store onboarding.**